# Can I call notification function in timer?

Tags: swift

I have func which return struct array of randomly generated cryptocurrencies and then passes it to tableView. 
I've got this error **Cannot convert value of type 'NSNotification.Name' to expected argument type 'Notification'** Am I heading in the right direction or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Notification.Name` is simply a String. What you need to do is construct a notification using this `Name`. In your `postNotification(notification:)` method, you are passing a `String`, not a `Notification`.

Try to replace this code: `postNotification(notification: Notificator.dataUpdateNotification)` with this: `postNotification(notification: Notification(name: Notificator.dataUpdateNotification))`.

You need to be passing a `Notification` into this method, but you are passing `Notification.Name` which is a `String`, not a `Notification`.

Comment: Thank you! Now the difference between these two is clear. I fixed the error but tableView is not updated. How do you think what I should change in code? May be a logic isn't right.

Comment: In `CryptoTableViewController`, do you have the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `numberOfRowsInSection:` methods declared with `quotes` behaving as the tableView’s data source?

Comment: Try explicitly unwrapping the dequeued cell by changing `if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “QuoteCell”, for indexPath: indexPath) as? QuoteCell` with `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: “QuoteCell”, for indexPath: indexPath) as! QuoteCell` and then take everything in the brackets out of the brackets. What may be happening is your cell isn’t being dequeued for some reason, like having an incorrect identifier. If this is the case, the app will have a fatal error on that line and we’ll be able to identify if that’s the cause.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed :( Thank you for your help! It seems like the problem lies elsewhere.